Clicker game feedback
Can someone please look at my clicker game and tell me if it is good and what to add?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/hamster-emoji-2048x1897-ccz0t29y.png">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
            <style>
                html{
                height: 100%
                }
                body{
                height: 100%; margin: 0px;
                }
                
                #hampter_clicker:active {
  /* Start the shake animation and make the animation last for 0.5 seconds */
  animation: shake 0.5s;

  /* When the animation is finished, start again */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.95); }
  10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg) scale(0.9); }
  20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg) scale(0.85); }
  30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.8); }
  40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg) scale(0.75); }
  50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg) scale(0.7); }
  60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.75); }
  70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg) scale(0.8); }
  80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg) scale(0.85); }
  90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.9); }
  100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg) scale(0.95); }
}
@keyframes clicker {
    0% { transform: translate(-5px, 0px)}
    20% { transform: translate(0px, 0px)}
}
@keyframes tilter {
    0% { transform: rotate(5deg)}
    12% { transform: rotate(0deg)}
    26% {transform: rotate(-5deg)}
    40% {transform: rotate(-5deg)}
}
#Cage_ID {
    animation: tilter 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#mouse {
    /* Start the shake animation and make the animation last for 0.5 seconds */
  animation: clicker 1s;

/* When the animation is finished, start again */
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}                

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  width: 59%;
  border: 3px solid BLACK;
}

.right {
  width: 39%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.tabcontent {
      animation: fadeEffect 1s; /* Fading effect takes 1 second */
    }
    
    /* Go from zero to full opacity */
    @keyframes fadeEffect {
      from {opacity: 0;}
      to {opacity: 1;}
    }
    .tab {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    /* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
    .tab button {
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    .tab button:hover {
      background-color: rgb (21, 105, 216);
    }
    
    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    .tab button.active {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    /* Style the tab content */
    .tabcontent {
      display: none;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-top: none;
    }
        .sidenav {
          height: 100%;
          width: 0;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 1;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          background-color: #111;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          transition: 0.5s;
          padding-top: 60px;
        }
        
        .sidenav a {
          padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 25px;
          color: #818181;
          display: block;
          transition: 0.3s;
        }
        
        .sidenav a:hover {
          color: #f1f1f1;
        }
        
        .sidenav .closebtn {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 25px;
          font-size: 36px;
          margin-left: 50px;
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
          .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
          .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
        }
        .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
        </style>
  
        <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Hampter Clicker</title>
       <!-- <script>
        $(window).load(function() {      //Do the code in the {}s when the window has loaded 
            $("#loader").fadeOut("fast");  //Fade out the #loader div
          });
          </script> -->
    </head>
    <body style="text-align: center;">
   <!-- <div id="loader"><img src='loader.gif'></div> -->
      <!-- <img  width="2000" height="2000" src="https://country1025.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/19/2023/09/GettyImages-1396578538-600x400-bf06395.jpg"> -->
        <header> 
            <img onclick="secretMessageButton1(1)" style="float: left; border-radius: 3px;" width="100" height="100" src="https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/tank-icon-2048x2048-n1ajz0u5.png" alt="Tank Icon">
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<button onclick="secretMessageButton1(100)">Add 100 clicks</button>
<button onclick="secretMessageButton1(1000)">Add 1k clicks</button>
<button onclick="secretMessageButton1(100000)">Add 100k clicks</button>
<button onclick="secretMessageButton1(1e+100000000000)">Add infinite clicks</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddCursor(10)">Buy 10 clickers</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddCursor(100)">Buy 100 clickers</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddCursor(1e+10000000)">Buy infinite clickers</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddWheel(10)">Buy 10 wheels</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddWheel(100)">Buy 100 wheels</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddWheel(1e+10000000)">Buy infinite wheels</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddCage(10)">Buy 10 cages</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddCage(100)">Buy 100 cages</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddCage(1e+1000000000000)">Buy infinite cages</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddHouse(10)">Buy 10 houses</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddHouse(100)">Buy 100 houses</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddHouse(1e+1000000000000)">Buy infinite houses</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddClickUPG(9)">Buy 9 Click Power Upgrades</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddClickUPG(10)">Buy 10 Click Power Upgrades</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddClickUPG(100)">Buy 100 Click Power Upgrades</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddClickUPG(1e+1000000000000)">Buy infinite Click Power Upgrades</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddClickerUPG(9)">Buy 9 Clicker Upgrades</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddClickerUPG(10)">Buy 10 Clicker Upgrades</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddClickerUPG(100)">Buy 100 Clicker Upgrades</button>
<button onclick="cheatAddClickerUPG(1e+1000000000000)">Buy infinite Clicker Upgrades</button>



            </div>
            <h1 style="text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000, 0 0 6px #000000;">Hammy Clicker<a id="back" href="https://militarymedia.github.io"><button id="back1">Back</button></a></h1>
        </header>

        <script src="buttonChanger.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="sheepy_activator.js"></script> -->
   
   <div>
   <div class="row" id="cursorBuy">     
   <div class="column left">
    <span id='sideNAV' style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; display: none; text-align: left;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    <!--<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks1" onclick="openCity1(event, 'click')" id='defaultOpen1'>Click</button>
      <button class="tablinks1" onclick="openCity1(event, 'HammyHome')">HammyHome</button>
      </div>
      <div id="click" class="tabcontent1">-->

   
            <p><span id="clicks">you are at 0 clicks</span><br>
                
           
               
                <img id='hampter_clicker'  style="border-radius: 50%;" width="225" height="225" onclick="hamsterclick(1)" src="click-hampter.jpg">
                <br>
                <br>
              <!--</div>
              <div id="HammyHome" class="tabcontent1">
                <p>Hammy Home level <span id="HammyLvl">1</span></p>
                <iframe width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" src="https://hammyhome.com?hh=('names!%255B'apKc4Kwb1Kh3Kh'%255D~props!%255B('bp!'noneKbHPPPKx!-0.05J0.52~z!-25.76G0S~HE1DABBKbhQG-1.15~yQOBFBFBF*R*ADADAD*R*P7FMKwlQ.8947788025203809~nhQG0.75SOR'G-1J0.1~HL*MMI*L*LKo!'c1N2Nf%252CsnNh%252Cbe')%255D)*%252C%2523G)%252C('x!Hc!'%2523RPJ~y!-K'~LEC76R00N%252CcO~rzQ~HPFFQ!0RIMSJ1.5%2501SRQPONMLKJIHG*_"></iframe>
              </div> -->
            </div><!--column 1-->
            <div class="column right">
              <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'buy')" id='defaultOpen'>Buy Helpers</button>
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'sell')" >Sell Helpers</button>
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'UPG')" >Buy Upgrades</button>
              </div>

          <div id="buy" class="tabcontent" style="overflow-y:scroll;">  
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">HELPERS</h2>  
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button id="clickerBuy" onclick="buyCursor()"><span id="cursors" >0x</span><b><img id="mouse" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61IHl1PNgPL._AC_UF894,1000_QL80_.jpg" width="55px" height="36px"><p id='cursor_img' > Clicker: $<span id="cursorCost">10</span></p></b></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button id="wheelBuy" onclick="buyWheel()"><span id="wheel">0x</span><b><img id="hampter_gif" src="hamster_wheel.gif" width="110px" height="72px"><p id="wheel_img">Wheel: $<span id="wheelCost">100</span></p></b></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button id="CageBuy" onclick="buyCage()"><span id="Cage">0x</span><b><img id="Cage_ID" src="hamster_cage.jpg" width="110px" height="72px"><p id="Cage_img">Cage: $<span id="CageCost">250</span></p></b></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button id="houseBuy" onclick="buyhouse()"><span id="house">0x</span><b><img id="house_ID" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/614aNCLdx1L._AC_UF1000,1000_QL80_.jpg" width="110px" height="110px"><p id="house_img">House: $<span id="houseCost">500</span></p></b></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button id="GodBuy" onclick="buyGod()"><span id="God">0x</span><b><img id="God_ID" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRK_c18wObI6jlqNbi8H9l4coI8UVcWede1uQ&s" width="110px" height="110px"><p id="God_img">God: $<span id="GodCost">100,000</span></p></b></button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>

          <div id="sell" class="tabcontent" style="overflow-y:scroll;">  
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">SELL HELPERS</h2>
            <br>
            <button onclick="sellCursor()"><p>Sell Clicker</p><br><span id="sellCursorAmount">You do not own any cursors!</span></button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="sellwheel()"><p>Sell Wheel</p><br><span id="sellWheelAmount">You do not own any wheels!</span></button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="sellcage()"><p>Sell Cage</p><br><span id="sellCageAmount">You do not own any cages!</span></button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="sellhouse()"><p>Sell House</p><br><span id="sellhouseAmount">You do not own any houses!</span></button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="sellGod()"><p>Sell God</p><br><span id="sellGodAmount">You do not own any Gods!</span></button>
            </div>
          
          <div id="UPG" class="tabcontent" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">UPGRADES</h2>
        

            <button onclick="buyclickingupgrade()"><p>Click Power lvl <span id="clickpowerUPG">1</span></p>
              <br>Cost: $<span id="clickpowerUPGcost">20</span>
              <br>Each upgrade level increases click power by 1.
            </button>
            <br><br>
    
            <button onclick="buycursorMult()"><p>Cursor Power lvl <span id="cursorMultUPG">1</span></p>
              <br>Cost: $<span id="cursorMultcost">110</span>
              <br>Each upgrade level increases cursor output by 1.
            </button>
            <br><br>
    
            <button onclick="buywheelMult()"><p>Wheel Power lvl <span id="wheelMultUPG">1</span></p>
              <br>Cost: $<span id="wheelMultcost">550</span>
              <br>Each upgrade level increases wheel output by 1.
            </button>
            <br><br>

            <button onclick="buycageMult()"><p>Cage Power lvl <span id="cageMultUPG">1</span></p>
              <br>Cost: $<span id="cageMultcost">975</span>
              <br>Each upgrade level increases cage output by 1.
            </button>
            <br><br>

            <button onclick="buyhouseMult()"><p>House Power lvl <span id="houseMultUPG">1</span></p>
              <br>Cost: $<span id="houseMultcost">1300</span>
              <br>Each upgrade level increases house output by 1.
            </button>
            <br><br>

                <button onclick="buyGodMult()"><p>God Power lvl <span id="GodMultUPG">1</span></p>
                  <br>Cost: $<span id="GodMultcost">195,000</span>
                  <br>Each upgrade level increases God output by 1.
                </button>
          </div>    
               
            
            </div><!--column 2-->
        </div>
      </div>
        <div><br>
        
        <br><br>
        <!-- WARNING: I HAVE NOT UPDATED THE FORMAT OF THE ITEM TEMPLATE BELOW. WILL TRY TO REMEMBER TO DO LATER-->
                <!--     The following is a template for a new item. ctrl + h and replace all "NEW_ITEM" in that section with the name for it. use the same name in the js file too or it will not work. also replace "NEW_IMG" with the url for the new image and the "NEW_IMG_ID" with the new id.-->
                <!--
                <p style="display: none;" id="NEW_ITEM_img">NEW_ITEM: <img id="NEW_IMG_ID" src="NEW_IMG" width="55px" height="36px"><span id="NEW_ITEM">0</span></p>
                <br>NEW_ITEM Cost: <span id="NEW_ITEMCost">100</span></p>
                <button onclick="buyNEW_ITEM()">Buy NEW_ITEM</button>    
                -->
                <button onclick='save()'>Save(local)</button>
                <button onclick='load()'>Load(local)</button>
                <button onclick="save2TXT()">Save(Code)</button>
                <input type='text' id='TXTload'><button onclick="loadFromtxt()">Load(Code)</button>
                <br>
                <span id="txtSaveNotification"></span><br>
                <span id="txtSave"></span>
           <!-- <button onclick="loadFile()">Load(File)</button> -->
           <!--<input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile"><button onclick="importfile()">Load file</button>-->
           <br>
       
          <!--<script type="text/javascript">
               document.getElementById('inputfile')
                   .addEventListener('change', function () {
       
                       let fr = new FileReader();
                       const import_save = fr.result.split(" ");       
                       //fr.readAstext(this.files[0]);
                   })
           </script>-->
           <script>
            
            function openCity(evt, buy) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
              tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
              tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(buy).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }

            function openCity(evt, UPG) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
              tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
              tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(UPG).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }

            function openCity(evt, sell) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
              tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
              tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(sell).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }

            
            function openCity1(evt, click) {
            var i, tabcontent1, tablinks1;
            tabcontent1 = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent1");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent1.length; i++) {
              tabcontent1[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks1 = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks1");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks1.length; i++) {
              tablinks1[i].className = tablinks1[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(click).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }

            function openCity1(evt, HammyHome) {
            var i, tabcontent1, tablinks1;
            tabcontent1 = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent1");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent1.length; i++) {
              tabcontent1[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks1 = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks1");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks1.length; i++) {
              tablinks1[i].className = tablinks1[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(HammyHome).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }
            </script>
            <script>
              // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
              document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
              document.getElementById("defaultOpen1").click();
              </script>

<script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }
  
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
  </script>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <h3>Anthony, Matthew, Nick, and Hampterkannone</h3>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>


function textChanger(input)
{
    document.getElementById(input).textContent = 'Go to '+input;
}
    
function textReverter(input)
{
    document.getElementById(input).textContent = input;
}
/*

ADD THIS TO BUTTONS TO MAKE THEM INTERACTIVE!
Change the Insert part to whatever the button is saposed to say.

id="Insert" onmouseover="textChanger('Insert')" onmouseleave="textReverter('Insert')"

*/
var saveAllowed = true;

var click = 0;
var message1 = 0;
var cursors = 0;
var wheel = 0;
var nextCost = 10;
var WheelnextCost = 100;
var Cage = 0;
var CagenextCost = 250;
var clickpower = 1;
var clickpowerUPGnextCost = 15
var cursorMult = 1;
var cursorMultnextCost = 100
var wheelMult = 1;
var wheelMultnextCost = 500;
var cageMult = 1;
var house = 0;
var houseMult = 1;
var God = 0;
var GodMult = 1;
/* following is part of template just replace "NEW_ITEM" with new item name */
/*
var NEW_ITEM = 0;
*/

function prettify(input){
    var output = Math.round(input * 100000000000)/100000000000;
    var output2 = output.toLocaleString();
    return output2;
}


function hamsterclick(input){
    click = click + input*clickpower;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";
}
function sellCursor(){
    if(cursors>=1){ 
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
    cursors = cursors - 1;
    click = click + cursorCost*0.6;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks."; 
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = prettify(cursorCost);
    document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors + 'x';
    if(cursors>=1){
        document.getElementById('sellCursorAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(cursorCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
    } else {
    document.getElementById('sellCursorAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any cursors!';
    }
    }   
}    
    
function sellwheel(){
    if(wheel>=1){ 
    var wheelCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,wheel));
    wheel = wheel - 1;
    click = click + wheelCost*0.6;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks."; 
    var wheelCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,wheel));
    document.getElementById('wheelCost').innerHTML = prettify(wheelCost);
    document.getElementById('wheel').innerHTML = wheel + 'x';
    if(wheel>=1){
        document.getElementById('sellWheelAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(wheelCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
    } else {
    document.getElementById('sellWheelAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any wheels!';
    }
    }   
}

function sellcage(){
    if(Cage>=1){ 
    var CageCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.1,Cage));
    Cage = Cage - 1;
    click = click + CageCost*0.6;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks."; 
    var CageCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.1,Cage));
    document.getElementById('CageCost').innerHTML = prettify(CageCost);
    document.getElementById('Cage').innerHTML = Cage + 'x';
    if(Cage>=1){
        document.getElementById('sellCageAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(CageCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
    } else {
    document.getElementById('sellCageAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any Cages!';
    }
    }   
}

function sellhouse(){
    if(house>=1){ 
    var houseCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.1,house));
    house = house - 1;
    click = click + houseCost*0.6;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks."; 
    var houseCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.1,house));
    document.getElementById('houseCost').innerHTML = prettify(houseCost);
    document.getElementById('house').innerHTML = house + 'x';
    if(house>=1){
        document.getElementById('sellhouseAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(houseCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
    } else {
    document.getElementById('sellhouseAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any houses!';
    }
    }   
}


function secretMessageButton1(input){
    click = click + input;
    document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = 'you are at ' + prettify(click) +' clicks.'
}

function buyCursor(){
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(click >= cursorCost){
        document.getElementById('cursor_img').style.display = 'block';                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        cursors = cursors + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        click = click - cursorCost;                          //removes the click spent
        document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = prettify(cursors) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = prettify(nextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
        document.getElementById('sellCursorAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(nextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
    };
}    
function buyWheel(){
        var WheelCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,wheel));     //works out the cost of this cursor
        if(click >= WheelCost){
            document.getElementById('wheel_img').style.display = 'block';                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
            wheel = wheel + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
            click = click - WheelCost;                          //removes the click spent
            document.getElementById('wheel').innerHTML = prettify(wheel) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
            document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
            var WheelnextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,wheel));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
            document.getElementById('wheelCost').innerHTML = prettify(WheelnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
            document.getElementById('sellWheelAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(WheelnextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
        };
};

function buyCage(){
    var CageCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.1,Cage));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(click >= CageCost){
        document.getElementById('Cage_img').style.display = 'block';                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        Cage = Cage + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        click = click - CageCost;                          //removes the click spent
        document.getElementById('Cage').innerHTML = prettify(Cage) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var CagenextCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.1,Cage));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('CageCost').innerHTML = prettify(CagenextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
        document.getElementById('sellCageAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(CagenextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
    };
};
//hi

var clickpowerUPGlvl = 1;
function buyclickingupgrade(){
    var clickUpgCost = Math.floor(15 * Math.pow(1.3,clickpowerUPGlvl));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(click >= clickUpgCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        clickpower = clickpower + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        clickpowerUPGlvl = clickpowerUPGlvl + 1;
        click = click - clickUpgCost;                          //removes the click spent
        document.getElementById('clickpowerUPG').innerHTML = prettify(clickpowerUPGlvl);  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var clickpowerUPGnextCost = Math.floor(15 * Math.pow(1.3, clickpowerUPGlvl));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('clickpowerUPGcost').innerHTML = prettify(clickpowerUPGnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
    };
};

var cursorMult = 1;
function buycursorMult(){
    var cursorMultCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.3,cursorMult));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(click >= cursorMultCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        cursorMult = cursorMult + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        click = click - cursorMultCost;                          //removes the click spent
        document.getElementById('cursorMultUPG').innerHTML = prettify(cursorMult);  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var cursorMultnextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.3, cursorMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('cursorMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(cursorMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
    };
};

var wheelMult = 1;
function buywheelMult(){
    var wheelMultCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.3,wheelMult));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(click >= wheelMultCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        wheelMult = wheelMult + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        click = click - wheelMultCost;                          //removes the click spent
        document.getElementById('wheelMultUPG').innerHTML = prettify(wheelMult);  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var wheelMultnextCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.3, wheelMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('wheelMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(wheelMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
    };
};

var cageMult = 1;
function buycageMult(){
    var cageMultCost = Math.floor(750 * Math.pow(1.3,cageMult));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(click >= cageMultCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        cageMult = cageMult + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        click = click - cageMultCost;                          //removes the click spent
        document.getElementById('cageMultUPG').innerHTML = prettify(cageMult);  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var cageMultnextCost = Math.floor(750 * Math.pow(1.3, cageMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('cageMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(cageMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
    };
};

var houseMult = 1;
function buyhouseMult(){
    var houseMultCost = Math.floor(1000 * Math.pow(1.3,houseMult));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(click >= houseMultCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        houseMult = houseMult + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        click = click - houseMultCost;                          //removes the click spent
        document.getElementById('houseMultUPG').innerHTML = prettify(houseMult);  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var houseMultnextCost = Math.floor(1500 * Math.pow(1.3, houseMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('houseMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(houseMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
    };
};

function buyhouse(){
        var houseCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.1,house));     //works out the cost of this cursor
        if(click >= houseCost){
            document.getElementById('house_img').style.display = 'block';                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
            house = house + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
            click = click - houseCost;                          //removes the click spent
            document.getElementById('house').innerHTML = prettify(house) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
            document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
            var housenextCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.1,house));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
            document.getElementById('houseCost').innerHTML = prettify(housenextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
            document.getElementById('sellhouseAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(housenextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
        };
};

function buyGod(){
  var GodCost = Math.floor(100000 * Math.pow(1.1,God));     //works out the cost of this cursor
  if(click >= GodCost){
      document.getElementById('God_img').style.display = 'block';                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
      God = God + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
      click = click - GodCost;                          //removes the click spent
      document.getElementById('God').innerHTML = prettify(God) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
      document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
      var GodnextCost = Math.floor(100000 * Math.pow(1.1,God));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
      document.getElementById('GodCost').innerHTML = prettify(GodnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
      document.getElementById('sellGodAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(GodnextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
  };
};

var GodMult = 1;
function buyGodMult(){
  var GodMultCost = Math.floor(150000 * Math.pow(1.3,GodMult));     //works out the cost of this cursor
  if(click >= GodMultCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
      GodMult = GodMult + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
      click = click - GodMultCost;                          //removes the click spent
      document.getElementById('GodMultUPG').innerHTML = prettify(GodMult);  //updates the number of cursors for the user
      document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
      var GodMultnextCost = Math.floor(150000 * Math.pow(1.3, GodMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
      document.getElementById('GodMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(GodMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
  };
};


function sellGod(){
  if(God>=1){ 
  var GodCost = Math.floor(100000 * Math.pow(1.1,God));
  God = God - 1;
  click = click + GodCost*0.6;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks."; 
  var GodCost = Math.floor(100000 * Math.pow(1.1,God));
  document.getElementById('GodCost').innerHTML = prettify(GodCost);
  document.getElementById('God').innerHTML = God + 'x';
  if(God>=1){
      document.getElementById('sellGodAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(GodCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';
  } else {
  document.getElementById('sellGodAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any Gods!';
  }
  }   
}


window.setInterval(function(){

  if(God >= 1){
      var GodPower = God*GodMult;
      secretMessageButton1(GodPower);
  };

  }, 1)

/* Following is part of template, replace "NEW_ITEM" with item name and "STARTING_COST" with starting cost of item */
/*
function buyNEW_ITEM(){
        var NEW_ITEMCost = Math.floor(STARTING_COST * Math.pow(1.1,NEW_ITEM));     //works out the cost of this cursor
        if(click >= NEW_ITEMCost){
            document.getElementById('NEW_ITEM_img').style.display = 'block';                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
            NEW_ITEM = NEW_ITEM + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
            click = click - NEW_ITEMCost;                          //removes the click spent
            document.getElementById('NEW_ITEM').innerHTML = prettify(NEW_ITEM) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
            document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
            var NEW_ITEMnextCost = Math.floor(STARTING_COST * Math.pow(1.1,NEW_ITEM));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
            document.getElementById('NEW_ITEMCost').innerHTML = prettify(NEW_ITEMnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
        };
};
*/





window.setInterval(function(){
if(cursors >= 1){
    
        var cursorPower = cursors*cursorMult*0.1;
        secretMessageButton1(cursorPower);
    
};
    //document.getElementById('hampter_clicker').style.animation="shake 0.1s"
}, 100);

window.setInterval(function(){

    if(wheel >= 1){
        var wheelPower = wheel*wheelMult*0.1
        secretMessageButton1(wheelPower);
    };

}, 20)

window.setInterval(function(){

    if(Cage >= 1){
        var cagePower = Cage*cageMult*0.1;
        secretMessageButton1(cagePower);
    };

    }, 10)

    window.setInterval(function(){

        if(house >= 1){
            var housePower = house*houseMult;
            secretMessageButton1(housePower);
        };

        }, 50)

/* following is part of template, replace "NEW_ITEM" with item name, replace "TIME_PER_CLICK" with the delay before you want to get 1 click (in milliseconds). */
/*
window.setInterval(function(){
    secretMessageButton1(NEW_ITEM);
    }, TIME_PER_CLICK)
*/
function save2TXT(){
   
    var obj = new String(click + ',' + cursors + ',' + wheel + ',' + Cage + ',' + clickpower + ',CHECK!?,' + clickpowerUPGlvl + ',' + cursorMult + ',' + wheelMult + ',CHECKSTRING,' + cageMult + ',' + house + ',' + houseMult + ',' + God + ',' + GodMult);
    console.log(obj);
    document.getElementById("txtSaveNotification").innerHTML = "The following is your save data. Keep it safe!";
    var base64EncodeString = btoa(obj);
    document.getElementById("txtSave").innerHTML = base64EncodeString;
  
}
function save(){
    var save = {
         click:click,
         cursors:cursors,
         wheel:wheel,
         Cage:Cage,
         clickpower:clickpower,
         clickpowerUPGlvl:clickpowerUPGlvl, 
         cursorMult:cursorMult,
         wheelMult:wheelMult,
         cageMult:cageMult,
         house:house,
         houseMult:houseMult,
         God:God,
         GodMult:GodMult// ADD COMMA WHEN ADD NEW ITEM BELOW
         /*
         NEW_ITEM:NEW_ITEM 
         */
    }
       localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
  };
  function load(){
  //clicks
    var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
       if (typeof savegame.click !== "undefined") click = savegame.click;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";
  //cursors
  if (typeof savegame.cursors !== "undefined") cursors = savegame.cursors;
  document.getElementById("cursors").innerHTML = prettify(cursors) + 'x';
  var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = prettify(nextCost);
        if (cursors >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellCursorAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(nextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellCursorAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any cursors!';}

//wheels
if (typeof savegame.wheel !== "undefined") wheel = savegame.wheel;
  document.getElementById("wheel").innerHTML = wheel + "x";
  var WheelnextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,wheel));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('wheelCost').innerHTML = prettify(WheelnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
  if (wheel >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellWheelAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(WheelnextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellWheelAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any wheels!';}

//cages  
  if (typeof savegame.Cage !== "undefined") Cage = savegame.Cage;
  document.getElementById("Cage").innerHTML = Cage + "x";
  var CagenextCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.1,Cage));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('CageCost').innerHTML = prettify(CagenextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
  if (Cage >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellCageAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(CagenextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellCageAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any cages!';}
 
//clickpower 
  if (typeof savegame.clickpower !== "undefined") clickpower = savegame.clickpower;

//click upg level  
  if (typeof savegame.clickpowerUPGlvl !== "undefined") clickpowerUPGlvl = savegame.clickpowerUPGlvl;
  document.getElementById("clickpowerUPG").innerHTML = clickpowerUPGlvl;
  var clickpowerUPGnextCost = Math.floor(15 * Math.pow(1.3,clickpowerUPGlvl));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('clickpowerUPGcost').innerHTML = prettify(clickpowerUPGnextCost);

//cursor upg lvl  
  if (typeof savegame.cursorMult !== "undefined") cursorMult = savegame.cursorMult;
  document.getElementById("cursorMultUPG").innerHTML = cursorMult;
  var cursorMultnextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.3,cursorMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('cursorMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(cursorMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user

//wheel upg lvl  
  if (typeof savegame.wheelMult !== "undefined") wheelMult = savegame.wheelMult;
  document.getElementById("wheelMultUPG").innerHTML = wheelMult;
  var wheelMultnextCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.3,wheelMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('wheelMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(wheelMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user

//cage upg lvl
  if (typeof savegame.cageMult !== "undefined") cageMult = savegame.cageMult;
  document.getElementById("cageMultUPG").innerHTML = cageMult;
  var cageMultnextCost = Math.floor(750 * Math.pow(1.3,cageMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('cageMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(cageMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user

//house
  if (typeof savegame.house !== "undefined") house = savegame.house;
  document.getElementById("house").innerHTML = house;
  var housenextCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.1,house));
  document.getElementById('houseCost').innerHTML = prettify(housenextCost);
  if (house >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellhouseAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(housenextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellhouseAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any houses!';}

//house upg lvl
  if (typeof savegame.houseMult !== "undefined") houseMult = savegame.houseMult;
  document.getElementById("houseMultUPG").innerHTML = houseMult;
  var houseMultnextCost = Math.floor(1000 * Math.pow(1.3,houseMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('houseMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(houseMultnextCost);


  
                            
  if (typeof savegame.God !==  "undefined") God = savegame.God;
  document.getElementById("God").innerHTML = God;
  var GodnextCost = Math.floor(100000 * Math.pow(1.1,God));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('Godcost').innerHTML = prettify(GodnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
  if (God >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellGodAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(GodnextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellGodAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any Gods!';}

  if (typeof savegame.God !==  "undefined") GodMult = savegame.God;
  document.getElementById("GodMultUPG").innerHTML = GodMult;
  var GodMultnextCost = Math.floor(150000 * Math.pow(1.3,GodMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('GodMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(GodMultnextCost);
  
  

  /* PART OF TEMPLATE, REPLACE "NEW_ITEM" WITH NEW ITEM NAME AND "STARTING_COST" WITH STARTING COST*/
  /*
    if (typeof savegame.NEW_ITEM !== "undefined") NEW_ITEM = savegame.NEW_ITEM;
  document.getElementById("NEW_ITEM").innerHTML = NEW_ITEM;
  if (NEW_ITEM >= 1) document.getElementById('NEW_ITEM_img').style.display = 'block';
  var NEW_ITEMnextCost = Math.floor(STARTING_COST * Math.pow(1.1,NEW_ITEM));
  document.getElementById('NEW_ITEMCost').innerHTML = prettify(NEW_ITEMnextCost);
  */

};



  function loadFromtxt() {

    const input = document.getElementById("TXTload");
const inputValue = input.value;
var txtDecodeString = atob(inputValue);

let TXTsavegame = txtDecodeString.split(",");

if (TXTsavegame[5] == 'CHECK!?' && TXTsavegame[9] == 'CHECKSTRING'){

if (typeof TXTsavegame[0] !==  "0") click = parseInt(TXTsavegame[0]);
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";

  if (typeof TXTsavegame[1] !==  "0") cursors = parseInt(TXTsavegame[1]);
  document.getElementById("cursors").innerHTML = prettify(cursors) + 'x';
  //if (typeof TXTsavegame.cursorCost !==  "0") cursorCost = TXTsavegame.cursorCost;
  //document.getElementById("cursorCost").innerHTML = cursorCost;

  var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = prettify(nextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
        if (cursors >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellCursorAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(nextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellCursorAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any cursors!';}

if (typeof TXTsavegame[2] !==  "0") wheel = parseInt(TXTsavegame[2]);
  document.getElementById("wheel").innerHTML = wheel;
  var WheelnextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,wheel));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('wheelCost').innerHTML = prettify(WheelnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
  if (wheel >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellWheelAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(WheelnextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellWheelAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any wheels!';}
 
  if (typeof TXTsavegame[3] !==  "0") Cage = parseInt(TXTsavegame[3]);
  document.getElementById("Cage").innerHTML = Cage;
  var CagenextCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.1,Cage));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('CageCost').innerHTML = prettify(CagenextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
  if (Cage >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellCageAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(CagenextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellCageAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any cages!';}
 
  if (typeof TXTsavegame[4] !==  "0") clickpower = parseInt(TXTsavegame[4]);
  
  if (typeof TXTsavegame[6] !==  "0") clickpowerUPGlvl = parseInt(TXTsavegame[6]);
  document.getElementById("clickpowerUPG").innerHTML = clickpowerUPGlvl;
  var clickpowerUPGnextCost = Math.floor(15 * Math.pow(1.3,clickpowerUPGlvl));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('clickpowerUPGcost').innerHTML = prettify(clickpowerUPGnextCost);

  if (typeof TXTsavegame[7] !==  "0") cursorMult = parseInt(TXTsavegame[7]);
  document.getElementById("cursorMultUPG").innerHTML = cursorMult;
  var cursorMultnextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.3,cursorMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('cursorMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(cursorMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
  
  if (typeof TXTsavegame[8] !==  "0") wheelMult = parseInt(TXTsavegame[8]);
  document.getElementById("wheelMultUPG").innerHTML = wheelMult;
  var wheelMultnextCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.3,wheelMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('wheelMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(wheelMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user

  if (typeof TXTsavegame[10] !==  "0") cageMult = parseInt(TXTsavegame[10]);
  document.getElementById("cageMultUPG").innerHTML = cageMult;
  var cageMultnextCost = Math.floor(750 * Math.pow(1.3,cageMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('cageMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(cageMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user

  if (typeof TXTsavegame[11] !==  "0") house = parseInt(TXTsavegame[11]);
  document.getElementById("houseUPG").innerHTML = house;
  var housenextCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.1,house));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('housecost').innerHTML = prettify(housenextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
  if (house >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellhouseAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(housenextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellhouseAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any houses!';}

  if (typeof TXTsavegame[12] !==  "0") houseMult = parseInt(TXTsavegame[12]);
  document.getElementById("houseMultUPG").innerHTML = houseMult;
  var houseMultnextCost = Math.floor(1000 * Math.pow(1.3,houseMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('houseMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(houseMultnextCost);

  
                        
  if (typeof TXTsavegame[13] !==  "0") God = parseInt(TXTsavegame[13]);
  document.getElementById("GodUPG").innerHTML = God;
  var GodnextCost = Math.floor(100000 * Math.pow(1.1,God));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('Godcost').innerHTML = prettify(GodnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
  if (God >= 1) {document.getElementById('sellGodAmount').innerHTML = 'You will earn $' + prettify(GodnextCost*0.6) + ' clicks.';} else {document.getElementById('sellGodAmount').innerHTML = 'You do not own any Gods!';}

  if (typeof TXTsavegame[14] !==  "0") GodMult = parseInt(TXTsavegame[131]);
  document.getElementById("GodMultUPG").innerHTML = GodMult;
  var GodMultnextCost = Math.floor(150000 * Math.pow(1.3,GodMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('GodMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(GodMultnextCost);
}else{
    alert('Invalid save. Please do not tamper with the save codes.');
}
}


  
  function onClickCode(cb) {
    var input = '';
    var key = '13161316';
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      input += ("" + e.keyCode);
      if (input === key) { // anthony ignore the fact that it says depreciated, it still works
        return cb();
      }
      if (!key.indexOf(input)) return;
      input = ("" + e.keyCode);
    });
  }
  
  onClickCode(function () {secretMessageButton1(1)})

  function onJudeSecret(cb) {
    var input = '';
    var key = '77505013'; // ma60--fel1\f#c but must be inserted backward with a slash at the begining
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      input += ("" + e.keyCode);
      if (input === key) { // anthony ignore the fact that it says depreciated, it still works
        return cb();
      }
      if (!key.indexOf(input)) return;
      input = ("" + e.keyCode);
    });
  }
  
  onClickCode(function () {secretMessageButton1(1)})

  function onOldSecretCode(cb) {
    var input1 = '';
    var key1 = '7765544849'; // ma60--fel1\f#c but must be inserted backward with a slash at the begining
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      input1 += ("" + e.keyCode);
      if (input1 === key1) { // anthony ignore the fact that it says depreciated, it still works
        return cb();
      }
      if (!key1.indexOf(input1)) return;
      input1 = ("" + e.keyCode);
    });
  }
  
  onOldSecretCode(function () {alert("The code got leaked, so it got changed. Sry to those people who are now suffering from the concequences, but ur not getting the code back.");})

  onJudeSecret(function () {document.getElementById('sideNAV').style.display = 'block';})


function cheatAddCursor(amount) {

        cursors = cursors + amount;
        document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = prettify(cursors) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = prettify(nextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
    
}
function cheatAddWheel(amount) {

        wheel = wheel + amount;
        document.getElementById('wheel').innerHTML = prettify(wheel) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var WheelnextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,wheel));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('wheelCost').innerHTML = prettify(WheelnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
}
function cheatAddCage(amount) {    
        Cage = Cage + amount;
        document.getElementById('Cage').innerHTML = prettify(Cage) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
        var CagenextCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.1,Cage));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
        document.getElementById('CageCost').innerHTML = prettify(CagenextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
}
function cheatAddHouse(amount) {    
    house = house + amount;
    document.getElementById('house').innerHTML = prettify(house) + 'x';  //updates the number of cursors for the user
    document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
    var housenextCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.1,house));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('houseCost').innerHTML = prettify(housenextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
}
function cheatAddClickUPG(amount) {    
    clickpower = clickpower + amount;
    clickpowerUPGlvl = clickpowerUPGlvl + amount;
    document.getElementById('clickpowerUPG').innerHTML = prettify(clickpowerUPGlvl);  //updates the number of cursors for the user
    document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
    var clickpowerUPGnextCost = Math.floor(15 * Math.pow(1.3, clickpowerUPGlvl));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('clickpowerUPGcost').innerHTML = prettify(clickpowerUPGnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
}

function cheatAddClickerUPG(amount) {    
    cursorMult = cursorMult + amount;
    document.getElementById('cursorMultUPG').innerHTML = prettify(cursorMult);  //updates the number of cursors for the user
    document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = "you are at " + prettify(click) + " clicks.";  //updates the number of click for the user
    var cursorMultnextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.3,cursorMult));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('cursorMultcost').innerHTML = prettify(cursorMultnextCost);  //updates the cursor cost for the user
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    if(isNaN(click) == true) {
    alert("Your game has been corrupted. Reloading game... ");
    location.reload();
}
}, 10000);

https://github.com/MilitaryMedia/MilitaryMedia.github.io is the github.
The clicker game code is in clicker.html and buttonchanger.js.
The website is https://militarymedia.github.io/clicker
I would love feedback on the game and just what to add.

Instead of asking a new question, you should have edited your previous one, reacting on the stated requirements.

"you are at xxx clicks" is warping left and right, make that smoother! perhaps a fixed width font or just update every second

Thanks a lot @todeskurve, I'll try that! I would just have to put something in the CSS to fix that, right?

@Hamsterguy You probably want a custom <div class="mono"> with .mono {font-family: monospace;}. Something similar to <code> without the code semantics.

@Peilonrayz I'll try that
